# Question about CollectionProperty and Polymorphism/inheritance

Tags: python, scripting, properties, collections

(Hi) I was wondering if its possible to create a `CollectionProperty` (`collection_custom_objects`) that contains, lets say a class `CustomObject(PropertyGroup)`, and then fill the collection with different objects that inherits that `CustomObject(PropertyGroup)` class?

For example, if we have:

```
# Base class
class CustomObject(PropertyGroup):
    ...

# Derived Classes
class ObjectA(CustomObject):
    ...

class ObjectB(CustomObject):
    ...
```

Is it possible to fill/add to the property with Objects of type ObjectA and/or ObjectB?

As far as I know, if we call `collection_custom_objects.add()`, we would be adding `CustomObject` objects.

I tried casting the item that `collection_custom_objects.add()` returns, like:

```
item = collection_custom_objects.add() # type(item) = CustomObject class
item = ObjectA(item) # If I print now type(item), I got "ObjectA class"
```

But when I get manually from the console that element previously added, it says its type is "CustomObject", and it calls the functions from "CustomObject", not from ObjectA.

So, I was wondering if this is something doable and I'm doing something wrong, or if it is not possible and I should give up this approach?

(Thank you so much for reading and for the help)

Comment: No is not possible. it only designed for one object type I think

Comment: nice to know! Thank for the help friend :)